# After importing the framework, I do not see any commands

Tags: swift, xcode

Im trying to work with SwiftyJson+Alamofire, and imported them to the project. 
Use Cocoapods file for install. It seems that everything is loaded, but when typing I do not see any commands except `AlamofireVersionNumber` and `SwiftyJsonVersionNumber`

[image]

I canot type `Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://www.example.com")
.responseString { response in
    print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")`

Comment: It's the Xcode voodoo, you just have to embrace the randomness of the availability of the autocompletion with this IDE. (More seriously : build the project first, if it has error, it panics and the autocompletion break).

Comment: Its so strange :-), I have not seen anything like this before in any IDE except Xcode

Comment: My Alamofire doesn't show either. you can just Alamofire and a . 
The autocompletion will appear.

Comment: @koropok I did not understand, what i have to do for appearing of autocompletion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clean project (⌘ + K) and after that build (⌘ + B).

Comment: The same) doesnt help)

Comment: @Romikromikromik, ok, just try to type "Alamofire." and you will see autocompletion.

Comment: Try Shift + Alt + ⌘ + K in order to also clean the derived data. Close / Reopen xCode and do a pod install inbetween... Sometimes, it works again (usually not).

Answer (score 1):

Try to build project (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>) first.

Comment: I did this but it does not help